# Java ArrayList update with points seems to replace all elements in said array with the most recent point

Tags: java, android, arrays

short description of what I am trying to do: I'm building a simple game where the user controls a vehicle and after some time more and more ghosts begin following the player, they follow the same trajectory as the player did with a delay.

To accomplish this I create an Array that contains the history of the player's location as a sequence of points. The problem, however, is that when I look at the data stored in this array I see that on all indices only the most recent location is stored.

First I create the array in a botManager class:

```
public class BotManager {

private ArrayList<Bots> bots;
private List<Point> history;

BotManager() {
    history = new ArrayList<>();
    bots = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Then in the update method of the manager class I add the current location of the player to the array

```
public void update(Point currLoc) {
    history.add(currLoc);

    for (Bots bot : bots) {
        bot.setLocationData(history);
        bot.update();
    }
}
```

A look at the update method in the main GameView class, in case I forgot something here

```
public void update() {
    player.update(playerPoint);
    botManager.update(playerPoint);
}
```

In the bots class' constructor I pass the history list (locationData) and determine its length to find out the delay in positioning. After which the following code handles the position of the bot.

```
@Override
public void update() {
    loc = locationData.get(delay - 1);
    this.rectangle = new Rect(loc.x - Constants.BOTSIZE/2, loc.y - Constants.BOTSIZE/2,
            loc.x + Constants.BOTSIZE/2, loc.y + Constants.BOTSIZE/2);

}
```

To get back to the problem, whenever I check the contents of the history array, I find that it only contains one point on all indices, and its the most recent even when I moved the player, causing the ghost to always remain on top of me.

So my question here is, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: can you post your full code here? I think you are clearing your history list each time you update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear from your posted code, but could it be, that you are just *modifying* the `Point` which you are adding instead *renewing* your object's Point objects?

Try

```
public void update(Point currLoc) {
    history.add(new Point(currLoc)); // new Point object added here

    for (Bots bot : bots) {
        bot.setLocationData(history);
        bot.update();
    }
}
```